# Google App Engine channel token is invalid

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, channel

I'm trying to open a channel by copying and pasting a token into an input box, however the console returns,

> Invalid+token.

Here is the code for localhost:8080/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
    <script>
      function OpenChannel(){
        channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(document.getElementById('Token').value);
        socket = channel.open();
        socket.onmessage = function(message){
          console.log(message);
        }
        socket.onopen = function(){
          connected = true;
          console.log('opened');
        }
        socket.onerror = function(err){
          console.log(err.description);
        }
        socket.onclose = function(){
          console.log('closed');
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
      Token: <input id="Token"></input><br/>
      <button onclick="OpenChannel()">Open Channel</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm creating the token by opening, "localhost:8080/token?name=...", which writes the channel token to the page. Here is the python class for that page:

```
class TokenPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    token = channel.create_channel(self.request.get('name'))
    self.response.write(token)
```

I've pretty much copied the documentation line for line, so I have no idea whats going wrong.

Solution:

replace

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>`

with

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>`
 .

Comment: And if you don't want or can't use script tag you can import it with it : https://github.com/Fantasim/app-engine-channel-js-api

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(document.getElementById('Token').value);
```

Comment: I still get the same error, but seeing that .innerHTML returns "" I should probably edit my question.

Comment: You might want to debug through your javascript and verify that you're actually submitting the correct token.

Comment: I solved it, I'll place the solution at the end of the question.