# import appengine channel js api without script tag

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm actually trying to use google channel api in javascript, it works perfectly with reactJS, but i would like use it on react-native.

So how can i import

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
```

I've tried to curl sources :`https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js` in my node module but it doesn't work (i get 401 error : `invalid+token`)

and as this people said on this topic : [Google App Engine channel token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114455/google-app-engine-channel-token-is-invalid) , only `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>` works

So how i can i do make it work Google appengine channel api in Javascript in react-native?

Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've created an npm module to import channel js api.

[https://github.com/Fantasim/app-engine-channel-js-api](http://app-engine-channel-js-api)